# enable software from CLI

Tags: command-line, 18.04, updates

How do you enable these sources from the CLI? I cannot see which it is in `/etc/apt/sources*`

[image: Software & Updates]

Comment: Check this file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. To edit it you must have a root privileges.

Comment: Yes, but which commented out section refers to which check box here?

Comment: Lines with "deb-src" on the beginning regards to the sources packages in the repository.

Comment: in short.. you want to control (tick and untick) the tick mark in your attached pic from command line rite?

Comment: @PRATAP yes, exactly. I can easily remove the comments via a bash script, but I can't find them! Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man sources.list` the main paragraph under`THE DEB AND DEB-SRC TYPES: GENERAL FORMAT` and some examples in it says

```
As an example, the sources for your distribution could look like this in one-line-style
       format:

           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
           deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted

       or like this in deb822 style format:

           Types: deb
           URIs: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
           Suites: xenial xenial-updates
           Components: main restricted

           Types: deb
           URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
           Suites: xenial-security
           Components: main restricted
```

Based on above:

and from the unedited `/etc/apt/sources.list` file from Ubuntu 18.04

Line 5 has two components i.e.,  main and restricted.

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

Line 16 has one component i.e., universe

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
```

Line 26 has one component i.e., multiverse

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
```

The 5th item in the attached pic, `source code` can be enabled by un-commenting the line number 6

```
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

---

Observations:

When you tick and untick these tick marks via GUI, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` lines may vary.. like they dont uncomment the line, Instead they will add other line with some comment etc..

If you dont change those settings with GUI, you can always edit the file with scripts with constant line numbers..

---

So be careful with your scripts while defining the line numbers..